# I couldnt connect to my MySQL server. But I don't think there's an error

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm doing my project both at house and at work. Although I'm just using a flash drive to keep it updated whenever I needed it. At my laptop, there is no MySQL password, but in my work there is.

Here's my connection string

```
<?php
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pass="";
    $db="librarydb";

    global $con;
    $con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Connection could not be made to the SQL Server.");
    mysql_select_db($db) or die ("Connection could not be made to the database.");
?>
```

Im doing this like 5 times now, and I don't know what happened.
Here is the error it gives me

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\OCatalog\admin\db_connection.php on line 8
Connection could not be made to the SQL Server.
```

But in my phpmyadmin, at the lower most part it gives me some kind of warning

```
 The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here.
```

I'm sure that whenever I go to work, I'm just filling up the password and then removing it whenever I go home so that I can use it, it is just today.

Comment: Do not use the depricated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or pdo.

Comment: Yeah i'm still adjusting. But what happened to my db_connection? Or phpmyadmin?